# Knockout binding order / without observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple viewmodel:

```
<input data-bind="value: url">
<a id=url-host data-bind="attr: { href: url }"></a>
<div data-bind="visible: isValidUrl">
    This is not a valid URL
</div>

function () {
    var self = this;
    self.url = ko.observable();

    self.isValidUrl = ko.computed(function () {
       return !!$("#url-host").get(0).protocol;
    });
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `isValidUrl` does not appear to be triggered when the input changes.  I can fix this by adding `self.url()` anywhere inside the `ko.computed` function.  It seems like `ko.computed` will only be triggered if it contains a call to an observable, which actually does make sense.

However, by adding `self.url()` to the code above, the `$("#url-host")` `href` attribute is actually still `undefined`.  This means that `isValidUrl` occurs *before* the `attr` set binding does.  My question is twofold:

1. How can I make sure that the `attr` value is set *before* the `isValidUrl` computed function runs?
2. Seemingly the `isValidUrl` should depend on the completion of the `attr` binding rather than the value.  Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: why take the url from the dom and not from the url variable?

Comment: @Circadian the `<a>` can be used like a Location object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not clear what you try to achieve. but you use knockoutjs to avoid this dom selection especially when you assign the url.

i have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXSSY/) which roughly does what I suspect you might want

```
self.isValidUrl = ko.computed(function () {
   return !!URI(self.url()).protocol();
});
```

I had to resort to Uri.js library since I couldn't find way to take the protocol from a string in plain javascript.

Comment: `self.url()` returns the value of the input, not the anchor

Comment: but you set the value of the input as anchor! so when you update the input you update the variable you update the isvalid

Comment: Can't see why this answer was down voted, it seems the best way to do it to me.  As a general rule, you should be avoiding accessing any UI elements from within your knockout models.

Comment: @DoctorMick I only do this so I can use the `<a>` as a location object; I could also create one on the fly which would do essentially the same thing, though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "throttle" extender to delay the evaluation of the computed observable:

```
self.isValidUrl = ko.computed(function () {
    self.url();
    return !!$("#url-host").get(0).protocol;
}).extend({ throttle: 1 });
```

However, note that the observable "url" is only updated once the input field looses focus, not while you're typing.

Comment: So is it common practice to call the observable dependency of the `computed` function as a noop to get it to trigger properly?

Comment: @ExplosionPills No, that actually indicates that you're applying the underlying concept in a wrong manner. When the content of the observable "url" changes the view is updated, ok so far. But you're then reading a value back from the view that was generated there based on the new value of "url" - which is just wrong, the view never generates any data (other than direct user input). This logic belongs in the ViewModel, so you should actually implement the URL validation in the computed observable using the content from `self.url()` and don't do such dirty tricks ;) (or live with this of course)

Comment: How can I use `self.url()` to do the validation in that case?

Comment: Well, you'd need to implement the validation logic by yourself or use any third-party library that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

ad 1. As soon as you make a call to `ko.applyBindings()` the DOM is going to be traversed and all bindings are resolved. The `url` variable is still `undefined` at that time because that is how you initialize it.

ad 2. Further, as you correctly stated, a `computed` variable should depend on an `observable`. If you don't want to do that (for whatever reason) you can still subscribe to your `url` observable and inside the callback refer to the `href` attribute. See [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) here.

```
myViewModel.url.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  // use $("#url-host") here
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a timing issue here:

1. The determination of whether to show the validation message is keying off the *true* value rather than the *false*. see html below or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/kUF2J/).
2. The anchor's protocol doesn't seem to behave the same in all browsers. In firefox protocol always returns "http" and in IE it does return what you type in. Might be different for others.

Getting the *isValidUrl* computed to fire more than once in this scenario does require a *trigger* and in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/kUF2J/) I used the url observable.

```
self.isValidUrl = ko.computed(function () {
    var trigger = self.url(); // trigger re-evaluation
   return !!$("#url-host").get(0).protocol;
});

<div data-bind="visible: !isValidUrl()">
    This is not a valid URL
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried initialising your observable with a blank value, to stop it being undefined?

```
self.url = ko.observable('');
```

And then referencing self.url() inside your computed (I think that you are correct in assuming that a computed should rely on an observable in your case).

You could also add the valueUpdate binding to your input:

```
<input data-bind="value: url, valueUpdate: keyup">
```

so that the value is updated with each key press, rather than when you blur out of the input.

Other than that, I'd say that you don't need the attr value to be set before isValidUrl runs. It will run each time you change the input value.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRZam/) with this code.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference (same if I initialize it to a specific value).  I guess my main question is how can I create a computed observable that depends on a value calculated from the DOM as opposed to a general KO binding

Comment: Well, it should make a difference to it being undefined. Have you put a break point inside your computed and see if it's being hit when you put text in the input?

Comment: Not without adding `self.url()` to the `computed` function

Comment: You need to put self.url in the computed. That's the point of computeds, they are computed off an observable. Look at my fiddle, and let me know what problem you have with it, as I think it's doing what you want, though you'd need to expand the is valid method to do some actual checking.